# Automating task of form filling using python requests

Tags: csv, python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to fill form multiple times using python requests. Data i am using is in csv. I am reading csv and filling form. But i am facing problem. It is filling form of only first row not all the rows.

These are codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
import json

username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"

url = "xxx"
parse_url = "xxx"

commerial_url = "xxx"

def Residential():
    global url, parse_url
    t1 = time.time()
    with open('Residential.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            builderid = row[0]
            buildername = row[1]
            buildingname = row[2]
            address = row[3]
            city = row[4]
            locality = row[5]
            building_id = row[6]
            property_type = list(map(int, row[7].split(",")))
            status = row[8]
            cdate = row[9]
            bhk = row[10]
            rnumber = row[11]
            rurl = row[12]

            payload = {"action":url,
                       "name":"",
                       "username":username,
                       "password":password,
                       "submit2":""}
            with requests.session() as s:
                s.post(url, payload)
                form_data = {"project[builderid]":builderid,
                             "buildingName":buildingname,
                             "project[address]":address,
                             "city_id":city,
                             "locality_id":locality,
                             "building_id":building_id,
                             "finalCityLocality":"",
                             "prop_types[]":property_type,
                             "1_type":1,
                             "2_type":1,
                             "3_type":1,
                             "4_type":1,
                             "6_type":1,
                             "7_type":1,
                             "90_type":1,
                             "22_type":1,
                             "project[flag]":status,
                             "readyToMoveDate":"",
                             "project[completion_dt]":cdate,
                             "launchDate":"",
                             "ex_id":"",
                             "ehome_visibility":"N",
                             "project[exid_type]":"",
                             "tagline":"",
                             "project[source]":"OTHER",
                             "project[source]":"rera",
                             "project[tco_visibility]":"N",
                             "project[carpet_area_visibility]":"N",
                             "project[pp_visibility]":"N",
                             "project[plan]":"",
                             "brochure_url":"",
                             "project[video_url1]":"",
                             "project[video_url2]":"",
                             "project[video_url3]":"",
                             "project[description]":"",
                             "project[proj_specifics]":"",
                             "project[data_reference]":rurl,
                             "usp[one]":"",
                             "usp[two]":"",
                             "usp[three]":"",
                             "logo_url":"",
                             "projArea":"",
                             "areaUnit":"ACRES",
                             "countTowers":"",
                             "countFloors":"",
                             "countUnits":"",
                             "percentOpen":"",
                             "payplan_url":"",
                             "project[meta_title]":"",
                             "project[meta_description]":"",
                             "show_bsp":"Y",
                             "price_type":"MIN_MAX",
                             "project[pmay_eligible]":"N",
                             "project[rera_status]":"",
                             "project[rera_af_date]":"",
                             "project[rera_regno]":"",
                             "project[rera_url]":"",
                             "project[rera_reg_startDate]":"",
                             "project[rera_reg_expDate]":"",
                             "project[rera_reg_extended]":"N",
                             "project[rera_inf_source]":"",
                             "project[rera_other_source]":"",
                             "project[sales_person_id]":"",
                             "auth_advt_add":"",
                             "cid":"",
                             "user":"",
                             "CMDSubmit":"SUBMIT"}
                s.post(parse_url, data=form_data)
                print(form_data)
                r = s.post(parse_url, data=form_data)
                print(r)
                t2 = time.time()
                total = t2-t1
                messagebox.showinfo("Info",f"Total Time taken to create residential xid is {total}")


root = Tk()
root.title("XID Creator")
v = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, text="Residential", variable=v, value=1,height=1,width=30, command=Residential).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(root, text="Commercial", variable=v, value=2,height=1,width=30, command=Commercial).pack(anchor=W)

root.mainloop()
```

whenever i click the residential it fills only one form row at one time, how can i make it to read all rows and fill form?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the loop is running more than once iteration?

Comment: Yes yes...it is reading csv till it's length. Reading all elements but not making multiple requests to fill form

Comment: So, that means you are calling `s.post(...)` and it's failing without throwing an error? Perhaps you should examine the result of the `post` -- there might be a failure message in it.

Comment: So what is happening here that it is reading csv and passing it's element into request and after that it's filling form perfectly but it doesn't loop over form however it loops over csv perfectly

Comment: It is not failing, it is filling form but doesn't loop again. It loops over csv perfectly ,reads it perfectly but doesn't loop over the html request

Comment: In an earlier comment you confirmed that it _is_ looping. Your first step needs to verify whether it is or isn't looping. Don't _assume_ it is looping, _verify_ it. Once you've established it is looping (and thus, _must_ call the code in the loop), you need to verify whether the code inside the loop is working or not.

Comment: It is reading csv perfectly and looping over it. But when i run it ,it reads only first row , filll form and stops. This is happening right now after debugging it even

Comment: How can it both "[read] csv perfectly and [loop] over it", and simultaneously stop after the first row?

Comment: Trust me. That's what i am asking to stackoverflow and my self. When i print s.post(..) it prints for only first row...and when i print any character of csv it prints complete csv

Comment: You are saying contradictory things. Until we clear the contradictions it's hard for us to help. Either it _is_ looping over every row, or it is _not_ looping over every row. You're claiming a) it's perfectly looping over the whole file, and b) stopping after the first row. It can't do both.

Comment: Yes sir, it loops over file and when i print it ,it prints file perfectly and when i click residential radio button ,it fills only first row in the form and stops. Could it be because of radio button?

Comment: Ok, so let's assume the loop is working. That means that the `s.post(...)` command is happening, because it must. You need to look at the result of that call to see why it is failing.

Comment: Yes sir, i am actually doing it. Will keep you posted once it is done. I don't know why people downvote questions they don't understand

Comment: _"I don't know why people downvote questions they don't understand"_ - that's exactly what voting is for. It says that the quality of the question is low, and because it's low it is hard to understand. The vote isn't against _you_, it's against the quality of the question.

Comment: There is a lot you can do to improve the quality. For one, you can remove all of the tkinter code since the problem is with looping and making a http request. The second would be to do as I say and examine the result of the call to `.post()` and include that in the question. Another would be to hard-code two rows of data so that we don't have to guess at the contents.

Comment: I'LL do that and will keep you informed

Comment: it is was because of return statement ,  return r when i removed that and clicked the button it was working as smooth

Comment: The code you posted does not have a `return` statement.

Comment: I edited it and posted new answer. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i solved it. I just removed return statement and everything was working as smooth..I have updated my code